# How to use logical operator in postgres json query where clause?

Tags: json, postgresql, logical-operators

I have a sales db

Example :-
# select * from sales;

```
 id |                         info              
        
----+-------------------------------------------------------

   1 | {"name": "Alice", "tags": ["admin"], "paying": true}

   2 | {"name": "Alice", "tags": ["admin"], "paying": false}

   3 | {"name": "Faber", "tags": ["admin"], "paying": false}
```

The OR Operator and AND operator does not give the correct results?

Example :-
# select * from sales where info ->> 'name' = 'Faber' OR 'paying' = 'true';

```
   id |                         info     
                 
  ----+-------------------------------------------------------

    3 | {"name": "Faber", "tags": ["admin"], "paying": false}

  (1 row)


 # select * from sales where info ->> 'name' = 'Alice' AND 'paying' = 'true';

    id | info 

   ----+------

   (0 rows)
```

Why are the operators not behaving in the way - they should behave?

Answer (score 0):

You are testing if the string 'paying' is equal to the string 'true', which it obviously is not.

If you want to test a field of json on each side of the logical, you need to repeat `info ->>` on each side of the logical.